# How to pass variable to SOAP Request. Variable contains a value read from xls using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have some set of data in xls for a SOAP webservice. Using Groovy script I can read the data and can print using variables. But how can I use this variable into Webservice XML. 
I feel Property Transfer feature won't help me here as value are being picked from XLS

Currently I have tried:

- in Groovy line is :

  ```
  def myTestCase = context.testCase;
  myTestCase.setPropertyValue("web:StateCode", d[1]);
  ```

OR

`testrunner.testcase.setPropertyValue("web:StateCode", d[1]);`

AND In SOAP Request I have passed variable as:

`<web:StatefCode>${d[1]}</web:StateCode>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. The easiest, which seems you are attempting, is to store the value in a test case property:

```
def data    // something from your Excel
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue('stateCode', data)
```

To use this in a subsequent request, use [property expansion](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html): `${TestCase#stateCode#}`.

Comment: SiKing...one more advice..writing code in SOAP UI doesn't show suggestion the way Eclipse shows for Java. So here syntex problem or available methods cant be seen also debugging not possible. is there any solution for it

Comment: @NipunKumar http://siking.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/debugging-soapui-groovy-scripts-in-eclipse/